# Time derivative in vacuum-to-vacuum transition amplitude for the real scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, path-integral

The vacuum-to-vacuum transition amplitude for the real scalar field has the following form
\begin{gather*}
W[J]
=
\mathcal{N}
\iint\text{D}\phi\text{D}\pi
\exp\left\{
\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}
\int\limits
\text{d}^4{x}
\left(
\pi
\partial_0\phi
-
\mathscr{H}
+
J\phi
\right)
\right\}
\end{gather*}
and if the lagrangian density can be written in the form
\begin{gather*}
\mathscr{L}
=
\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\partial_0\phi\partial^0\phi
+f(\phi,\nabla\phi)
\end{gather*}
then it should be
\begin{gather*}
\pi\doteq\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\partial_0\phi)}=\hbar^2\partial^0\phi
\end{gather*}
but turns out that I **cannot** substitute $\partial^0\phi\to\pi/\hbar^2$ inside $W[J]$ (for example as stated in pag. 351 Greiner "Field Quantization" (1996) without further argumentation). Seems that the one inside the definition of $W[J]$ and the one inside the definition of $\pi$ are two very different kinds of temporal derivatives of the field.

Can you explain why is that?! I really can't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lagrangian form of the path integal is different from the Hamiltonian path integral  your question  starts with.  In the Hamiltonian path integral you integrate over $\pi$ and $\phi$ as completely independent variables. In the Lagrangian form, $\partial_0 \phi$ is determined by $\phi(t)$ and is not independent of it. You can (formally) get the Lagrangian form by doing the path integral over $\pi$, but in doing this integral you are integrating over field configurations  in which $\pi \ne \partial_0 \phi$, so it is not surprising that you cannot just substitute  one for the other.

Even in classical mechanics you have to be careful.  If your write the Lagrangian for a central force problem in terms of $L(r,\theta)$, the $\theta$ equation gives you  that $l= r^2\dot \theta$ is constant, but you can't replace $\dot \theta$ in $L$ by $l^2/r$ and get an effective $L$ for the radial motion, You need instead to go through the Routhian construction. The reason is a similar one to your issue.

Comment: So you are saying that I can do the substitution if only the field is following the equation of motion, meaning that both $\phi$ and $\pi$ follow Euler-Lagrange equations. But in integrating over the $\phi$ and $\pi$ configurations I'm not caring about the physical evolution of the field. Is this the problem? The difference you are making between lagrangian and hamiltonian formalism, has to do with the very presence of $\pi$? I suspect it is.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, why in the hamiltonian density $\mathscr{H}=\pi\partial^0\phi-\mathscr{L}$ I can do the substitution $\partial^0\phi=\pi/\hbar^2$? Is it because in the lagrangian and hamiltonian density I must consider only the "effective" field, following Euler-Lagrange equations?

Comment: In what sense do you mean when you say you can  "do the substitution $\partial^0=\pi$"?  The statement  $\partial_0 \phi=\pi$  an *equation of motion*, and you can not  substitute a  consequnce of an equation of motion back into the action even in a classical theory.

Comment: I mean that I find in books that is possible to write $\mathscr{H}=\pi^2/\hbar^2-\mathscr{L}=\pi^2/(2\hbar^2)-f(\phi,\nabla\phi)$ without so much pain, but I can't go so easy with $W[J]$ because in that case $\pi$ is like a new "degree of freedom". I don't know how to explain it better sorry, I'm practically left alone in learning this stuff.